# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, ... receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set

Tags: android, flutter

I already added android:exported="true" to all the activities in my manifest file but still got the following error:

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher.

This is my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nelinik.TheQuizBattleApp">
    <queries>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
    </queries>
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- needed for notifications-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="The Quiz Battle"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Facebook -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <meta-data android:name = "com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value = "@string/facebook_client_token" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- Add Mob -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9722761268400847~5659867972"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>``
```

Comment: I think you forgot receiver initialization in your project's manifest like below

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.youorg.yourproject">
  <application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication">
    <receiver
      android:name=".MyReceiver"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="io.sdk.RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>

Comment: It's also not working with a receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the app with Android 12. The console displayed which manifest file caused the error.
It was a manifest file from a plugin.

There are two options to solve the problem:

1. update the plugin, the problem might be solved with a newer version
2. add the 'android:exported' property to the file of the plugin